# Where can I find a good questions/answers script?

Tags: script

I want to avoid reinventing the wheel and would like to purchase a good question and answer script/software. Where can I find a good one?

Comment: Read through here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could have a look at [SOClone](http://code.google.com/p/soclone/) or [Shapado](http://gitorious.org/shapado) ( [sneak peak of a site on Shapado](http://shapado.com/))

Answer (score 3):

See [www.stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com).

It's not cheap though.

Comment: Wow..you are not kidding..Do you know of a cheaper alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it may be good idea to create it on a Content Management System (CMS) such as Drupal.

It shouldn't take much time if you are not looking for many features.